# How to embed text in textarea of mailform bei clicking on button

Tags: javascript

What code would I need to embed a given text in the text area of a mail form by clicking on a button which is on another page of the same site? I've tried the following to no avail (where am I making the mistake?):

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit request</button>

<p id="request"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("request").textarea.kontakt.html = "My text.";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById("id-of-the-textarea").value = "My text.";`

Note : Your above code should be :

```html
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit request</button>

<p id="request"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("request").innerHTML = "My text.";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Well, actually, I ran your code on the site I built, all in HTML, changing the id to the id of the textarea, which is "message", and then putting all sorts of combinations for the ".value" (./kontakt.html, ./kontakt, .kontaktHTML, .value, .innerHTML) but none worked!, because the button will be on the index.html page and the message should appear in the text area of the contact form, which has the name /kontakt.html. So, where am I still making the mistake? I appreciate your suggestions. Thanks in advance! :-)